# How to authenticate WebSocket within an existing HTTP environment with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have a pretty simple requirement (I use Spring-Security 4.0.1) but I can't find any examples on the web except what is been told on this page: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-handler

> It is relatively simple to integrate a WebSocketHandler into other
>   HTTP serving environments with the help of
>   WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.

**What I have**: An implementation of `WebSocketHandler` that does the job and an HTTP serving environments using a *Basic Authentication*.  My `WebApplicationInitializer` looks like this:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        ...
        // WebSocket support - Handshake
        Dynamic ws = servletContext.addServlet("webSocketHttpRequestHandler", new HttpRequestHandlerServlet());
        ws.addMapping("/streaming/*");

        // Spring Security Filter
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurity = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        springSecurity.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
    }
}
```

This is how I plugged my websocket endpoint to my existing web application. 
My WebSocket configuration class looks like (very simplified) this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketServicesConfig{
    @Bean
    public WebSocketHttpRequestHandler webSocketHttpRequestHandler() {
        return new WebSocketHttpRequestHandler(new StreamingWebSocketHandler());
    }
}
```

`StreamingWebSocketHandler` implements `WebSocketHandler`.

I also have a *RESTful Web Service* (in the same server) that uses the configured Basic Authentication.

**What is working**: My RESTful Web Service is working with any web browsers. I can do some authenticated queries (credentials can be sent in the HTTP headers). 
WebSocket queries are working and ask for authentication the first time I try to do some (under FireFox, a popup appears asking for credentials, once I enter them, client and server are able to communicate via WebSocket messages). 
In my `WebSocketHandler`, the Spring object: `WebSocketSession` that contains informations about the authenticated user is correct (`#getPrincipal()` method returns a `Authentication` containing the right granted Authorities, details and so on...). 
Note that once the websocket is authenticated, I can relaunch the query without re-enter them.

**What I want**: On a user point of view, this is bad because the credentials are required twice:

1. First for RESTful queries
2. Second for WebSocket queries

**How can I *bypass* the second authentication assuming the first one succeeded?** Is there a way to detect the client has been authenticated and not ask for credentials?

**What I don't want**: I don't want to use neither [Stomp over websocket](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-overview) nor SockJs (I don't need to support old web browsers).

Comment: I think I have finally found the answer but I'm not totaly sure. Once I'm already authenticated into the application, the handshake request does not bring about the "credentials popup". By looking to the handshake request parameters/cookies (in FF developer tool for instance), it can be deduced that the cookie JSESSIONID must be present in the request. This can be done by doing a proper login action (I should set up a login page for instance). Then the web browser will use that cookie in the next requests including the websocket handshakes.